# Docker Hub - Automated build linked to Bitbucket

Tags: docker, bitbucket, dockerhub

Automated build on Docker Hub - I see no repositories when linking?

1. I have created an account on Bitbucket which is attached to a repository (no team, no group, just a user on a prepository).
2. In Docker Hub, I tried to link to Bitbucket via button + Add Repository / "Automated Build".
3. I get logged in alright, but it says "No repos available".

That is strange as I can see the repository when logged into Bitbucket with this specific user.
I have created this Bitbucket user for the sole purpose of being able to see that repository.

Comment: what is attached repository? just create repo and refresh the page, it will show up.

Comment: The "attached repository?", I guess is a message from Docker Hub, when trying to "hook" into BitBucket. Nope, there is no repositories refreshing or not.

Comment: I had save problem wtih Git which solved by verifying my email address. Git didn't allow users w/o verified email to be publicly associated with repositories. Maybe bitbucket has the same policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - it seems that the linked user should be "owner" or "creator" of the repository.

Tests:

- I added additional user to the BitBucket repository as "admin" (also with read & write permissions) and tried to link this user.

  The result: "No repos available"
- Then, I tried the same with "owner" and "creator" accounts of the repository and it worked.

So, you should try to link users which are authorized as "owner" or "creator":

Go to Bitbucket repo -> Settings -> Access management -> Users - try only with "owner" or "creator" accounts

Don't forget to unlink the old accounts:

- in Bitbuket: OAuth in "Manage account" -> "ACCESS MANAGEMENT" -> "OAuth"
- in Docker Hub: "Profile settings" -> "Linked Accounts"